# Typescript return typeof this

Tags: typescript

I'm looking for the correct way of returning the type of `this` from an implementation of an abstract method. Like the `self` in PHP.

I've tried this very basic example:

```js
abstract class Listable {
  public abstract list(): (typeof this)[]; //bad syntax
}

class SomeList extends Listable {
  public list(): SomeList[] {
    return [new SomeList, new SomeList, new SomeList];
  }
}
```

This is - however - bad syntax. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use a [`this` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) as follows:

```
abstract class Listable {
  public abstract list(): this[];
}

class SomeList extends Listable {
  public list(): this[] {
    return [this];
  }
}

const l = new SomeList().list(); // type of l is SomeList[]
```

Comment: Nice, I missed updating the return type of the SomeList list method

Comment: Yes, for my first example, that works. Not entirely what I mean tho and I see it's my fault for not being clear. This does not work for my edited example, which is more what I mean.

Comment: I saw your ThisType answer before you removed it. If you can readd that one I can mark it as solved - because that is the answer is was looking for.